# Is it possible to add a table (with links to records) on to an object rather than using a related list?

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I'm not sure if I am the exception here, however when it comes to using Salesforce1 I'm not a big fan of having to:

1. swipe across to get to the list of "related lists", then
2. select the related list that I want, then
3. get the list of records in the list (not sure what the correct name for this view is), then
4. select the related record to view it.

***Background***:

We have an integration with Infor LN that creates invoice object records which appear in a related list to the account.  Then the invoice lines are their own object on a related list to the invoice. The PDF of the invoice is an attachment to the invoice which is of course accessed via a related list. This means a ridiculous amount of swiping and select the related list you want and then the record you want - it's not elegant at all.

Yes I admit that the integration (Inforce) doesn't help with the above structure, but I was hoping to improve on this by bypassing the related lists.

For example:

Could I create a table of invoice lines on the invoice object, with the key info off the invoice line record and have this table render ok in SF1 on the invoice record? That way the user may not need to go to the invoice line and even if they did, ideally they should be able to click on the name of the line in the table being a hyperlink to the invoice line record.

Does anyone have any advice as to whether this is possible? And, if so, what the best approach may be?

Thanks so much for the help with this!

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce1 supports Visualforce. This means that it would be trivial to create a so-called "mobile card" to show whatever information you like. Of course, you'll still have to swipe from the account to get to the data, but it'll save you a few swipes.

Basically, you create a Visualforce page, mark it as mobile ready, then add it to the page layout. The standard controller for the page must be for the parent object, and since the default model only allows one sub query (you need two), you'll also need an extension.

You might also consider making a custom field on the line item that references the account, then use a trigger to populate the data (you can make triggers on custom objects in a managed package). This would let you build a related list to see all the items, although it wouldn't be as legible as a Visualforce page.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!  I will give this a go and come back to you - may take me a little while to implement under current work load, but I will be back with progress update and all going well a best/accepted answer for you.

Comment: @Cerbera if you need help, feel free to reach out. I'm employed full time, but I do try to help where I can.